# Hiding dock icon when application is hidden

Tags: .net, macos, maui, mac-catalyst

How can I hide the dock icon of my MacCatalyst app, developed using .net 7 MAUI, when the app is hidden by either minimizing it or using the "CMD+H" command? I have tried changing the info.plist by setting the LSUIElement key entry to String 1 as suggested online, but it doesn't seem to work. Are there any other methods to achieve this behavior?

I have tried changing the info.plist by setting the LSUIElement key entry to String 1 as suggested online, but it doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the LSUIElement key as String true or Boolean Yes instead of String 1.

> LSUIElement (Boolean - macOS) specifies whether the app runs as an agent app. If this key is set to YES, Launch Services runs the app as an agent app. Agent apps do not appear in the Dock or in the Force Quit window. Although they typically run as background apps, they can come to the foreground to present a user interface if desired. A click on a window belonging to an agent app brings that app forward to handle events.

> The Dock and loginwindow are two apps that run as agent apps.

You can refer to the [official document about the LSUIElement](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/LaunchServicesKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001431-108256).